# Get ID of saved pivot-item

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I would like to solve the following problem:

I have a model (`Car`) that is loaded as a relation to another model (`Driver`) with a pivot table.

**Car -> belongsToMany Driver (with pivot)  -> belongsToMany Accessoires (with Pivot).**

The model in turn has relations (`accessories`) that are loaded with pivot.

The problem: The model `Accessories` has two pivot tables which can be loaded depending on other factors. If the model `Accessories` is loaded as a relation of `Driver` as a relation of `Car`, the pivot tables should be output correctly.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

```
 collect($request->input('data.driver'))->each(function ($driver) use
        (
            $car
        ) {

            $ndriver = Driver::findOrFail($driver['id']);

            $added = $car->driver()->save($driver, [
                'custom' => $driver['custom'],
                'title' => $driver['title'],
                'factor' => $driver['factor'],
            ]);

            /*Save attributes*/
            $added->syncDriverAttributes($driver['attributes']],
                $car->id);
        });
```

Now I should actually specify in `$added->syncDriverAttributes($driver['attributes'], $car->id);` the pivot ID of the created pivot data in `$added`. Unfortunately I can't find out what the pivot ID is at the moment, because it is not returned in `$added`.

The problem: I can't find out the last pivot ID from the timestamp either, because all entries have the same timestamp.

So my question is: How can I solve that?

Comment: A pivot table usually does not have an `id` column. The primary key is a composite of the two model keys being linked. So `accessories_drivers` would have `accessory_id` and `driver_id` as a composite primary key.

Comment: Okay, I understand that. I added a `bigIncrements` to `accessories_drivers` hoping that I could get a return. How else can I solve that issue to link the pivot to a specific `car`, `driver` and `accessory? Maybe I could generate a  UUID and save this as `pivot` for `$car->driver()` and reference that as foreign key in the `pivot` for a `accessory`?

Answer (score 0):

You can of course do it but you should use `withPivot` method when defining your relationship to tell what additional fields you want to have:

```
public function driver()
{
   return $this->belongsToMany(Driver::class)->withPivot(['id']);
}
```